# Convert JSON formated String to JsonObject with Jayrock

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-2, jayrock

I have a request parameter in my ASP.NET app. that is in JSON format, and I was wondering if there is a good (quick and easy) way to convert a JSON string to a Jayrocks JsonObject, so I can easily extract key-value pairs without the need to manually parse the string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `json` is the variable containing JSON text, use `Jayrock.Json.Conversion.JsonConvert.Import(json)`. What you will get back in return is either a `JsonObject`, `JsonArray`, `JsonNumber`, `System.String`, `System.Boolean` or a null reference depending on the root JSON value in the source JSON text. If you know it is going to be a JSON object for sure then you can safely cast the return value or use `JsonConvert.Import<JsonObject>(json)`.

I would discourage working against `JsonObject` directly unless you particularly depend on one of its features. You should just pretend the JSON object you get back is a dictionary; either `IDictionary` or `IDictionary<string, object>`. With the latest version for .NET Framework 4, you can also work with a `JsonObject` as a *dynamic* object.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Jayrock, but if you want to accept a JSON object as a parameter of Action in MVC2 than the easiest way to do it is by using **[JsonValueProviderFactory](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx)** from Futures assembly.

It's part of System.Web.Mvc in MVC3.